# Use lodash _.sortby to sort an array of contacts with details and send null values last?

Tags: javascript, sorting, lodash

I have an array of contacts with details such as email, phone#, etc. These contacts are all sorted by name. However, while every contact must have these details, they do not always have a Name assigned. Is there a simple argument I can add to send these contacts with a null Name value to the end of the list? What I have now.

```
array=_.sortBy(array,'Name');
return array;
```

Comment: What's an example input, output, and desired output of yours? _.sortBy already puts null values to the end of the list

Comment: @sbrass An example would be the contacts with names sorted alphabetically, and the contacts without a name value are sent to the bottom of the list. Right now the null values are first and the rest of the sorting comes after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way for lodash, but it's easy enough with plain js

```js
let arr = [{
  name: null
}, {
  name: 'foo'
}, {
  name: 'bar'
}, {
  name: null
}];
arr.sort((a, b) => a.name === null ? Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER : a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This works great.. can I ask: is there any real advantage to using the lodash _sortBy method instead of the plain js sort?

Comment: No, there’s no advantage in using lodash and plain js is most likely faster @OmarA

Answer (score 2):

You could use a function in the iteratees for sorting falsy values to bottom.

```js
var users = [{ name: null }, { name: 'susan' }, { name: 'barney' }, { name: 'fred' }, { name: 'jane' }, { name: null }];

console.log(_.sortBy(users, [({ name }) => name === null, 'name']));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```